# How can I access BadgerFish notated attributes using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, xml, json

I have created a json object from ruby with cobravsmongoose, however the attributes have the **`@`** symbol in front of them.  Whenever I try to access them with standard object notation in JavaScript, such as `object.object.object.@attribute` I get a *parse error*.  Is there another way to access these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab your JSON as a string instead. Do a replace to clean up the @ symbols, and recreate it as JSON.

Comment: Wouldn't that be very CPU intensive either in Ruby, or in JavaScript on the client.  Wouldn't it be better to just modify the library?

Comment: It's just a simple string replace. I'd do it on the client. Unless you're getting a megabyte of data it will take milliseconds. There's no complexity in the data to dance through yet - it's just a blob of text.

Answer (score 1):

You can also access your object attributes with subscript notation:

```
object.object['@attribute']
```

But it's better to do as @Diodeus proposed